# Running a macro multiple times

Tags: vba

Suppose I have a macro that copies and pastes a number from cell A1 to cell B1, from cell A2 to B2 etc. I record this macro. If I have a column of numbers in A how would I run the macro multiple times without having to manually run it for each one?

Here is the example:

```
    A    B
    1    1    #copies number from column A to column B
    2    2
```

I don't want to have to press hot keys on each cell in A to run the macro. I want to just run the macro for all the values in column A at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just do:

```
Columns("A").Copy Range("B1")
```

That will copy all of column A into column B.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. This will count down until the three is subracted to 0. You could replace it with the count of how many rows are filled in - 1.

```
Sub Test()
Call RunMainMacro(3) 'run macro 3 times
End Sub

Sub RunMainMacro(ByRef Times)
Do
    Application.Run " 'project1.xlsm'!MainMacro"
    Times = Times - 1
    DoEvents
Loop Until Times = 0
End Sub
```

From

Comment: That will copy A1 to B1 three times.

Comment: Yes. Hence my sentence at the top.